# How to display data from socket.io connection?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets

I am trying to use socket.io to transfer data from a node.js script to an HTML webpage.  The node.js script is executing a function (that uses a BeagleBone Black sensor) and returning a certain value.  I want to transfer this value via a socket to the HTML page.  I then want the HTML page to display this value.  I have been able to get the webpage to log everything on Chrome's Javascript console.  I don't understand though why the data is not being printed on the actual page.

```
// Install socket.io: terminal, goto /var/lib/cloud9 and enter: npm install socket.io

var app = require('http').createServer(handler);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

var fs = require('fs');

var b = require('bonescript');

var fulldata = 0;
// count how many pulses
var pulses = 0;
// track the state of the pulse pin
var lastflowpinstate;
//time between pulses
var lastflowratetimer = 0;
// used to calculate a flow rate
var flowrate;
// Interrupt is called once a millisecond, looks for any pulses 
var value = 0;

var liters = 0;


app.listen(8090);

/* socket.io options go here

io.set('log level', 2);   // reduce logging - set 1 for warn, 2 for info, 3 for debug

io.set('browser client minification', true);  // send minified client

io.set('browser client etag', true);  // apply etag caching logic based on version number
*/

console.log('Server running on: http://' + getIPAddress() + ':8090');

var Sensor = "P8_19";
b.pinMode('P8_19', b.INPUT);
console.log(b.digitalRead('P8_19'));

function handler (req, res) {

  if (req.url == "/favicon.ico"){   // handle requests for favico.ico

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );

  res.end();

  //console.log('favicon requested');

  return;

  }

  fs.readFile('SensorHTML.html',    // load html file

  function (err, data) {

    if (err) {

      res.writeHead(500);

      return res.end('Error loading index.html');

    }

    res.writeHead(200);

    res.end(data);

  });

}



io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    setInterval(function() {

            //doSomething();
            b.pinMode('P8_19', b.INPUT);
            value = b.digitalRead('P8_19');

            if (value == lastflowpinstate) 
            {
            lastflowratetimer++;
            //return; // nothing changed!
            }

            if (value == '1') 
            {
               //low to high transition!
               pulses++;
            }

            lastflowpinstate = value;
            flowrate = 1000.0;
            flowrate /= lastflowratetimer;  // in hertz
            lastflowratetimer = 0;

            liters = pulses / (450);
            fulldata += liters;
            JSON.stringify(fulldata);
            //send temperature reading out to connected clients
            socket.emit('water', {'water': fulldata});

    }, 500);

    //function doSomething() {

 });

  // Get server IP address on LAN
  function getIPAddress() {

  var interfaces = require('os').networkInterfaces();

  for (var devName in interfaces) {

    var iface = interfaces[devName];

    for (var i = 0; i < iface.length; i++) {

      var alias = iface[i];

      if (alias.family === 'IPv4' && alias.address !== '127.0.0.1' && !alias.internal)

        return alias.address;

    }

  }

  return '0.0.0.0';
}
```

And the HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
 <!-- include bootstrap, jquery for easy div manipulation -->
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>SmartWater</h1>
 <th>Flow (liters)</th>
 <script>

 var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.7.2:8090/');  //enter the IP of your beaglebone and port you are using in app.js

 socket.on('water', function(data) {
 //$('#').html(data.full_data);
    $('#water').html(data.fulldata);
    console.log(data.fulldata);
 });

</script>
<div id="water"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of socket.io are you running?  The latest socket.io doc shows `io.on('connection', function() {...})`, not `io.sockets.on('connection', function () {...});`

Comment: FYI, you also need to listen for the disconnect event because otherwise your `setInterval()` goes forever even on closed sockets.  You will need to stop the interval timer when the socket is closed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I must have overlooked it.  I fixed that though, but I still get no output on the webpage, although the console does get data.

Comment: What do you mean the "console does get data"?  What shows in the server console?  On the client console?

Comment: Also, FYI you should not be calling `JSON.stringify(fulldata)`.  Remove that line.

Comment: The server console has nothing other than "Server running on: 192.168.1.16:8090,"; which is what I asked it to log.

Comment: The client console has "socket.io-client:socket emitting event %j +502ms ["water", Object](index):19 undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the client, change:

```
$('#water').html(data.fulldata);
console.log(data.fulldata);
```

to this:

```
$('#water').html(data.water);
console.log(data.water);
```

The property name you're setting on the server is `water`, not `fulldata`.

---

Also, on the server, remove this line:

```
JSON.stringify(fulldata)
```

There is no need to stringify a single number that is just being passed as a property on an object.  In fact, it will probably cause a problem for you.

---

On the server, you will also need to save the timer from the call to `setInterval()` so you can `clearInterval()` when the socket is disconnected.  I would suggest storing the interval timer handle as a custom property on the socket object itself as that will make it easier to access in the `'disconnect'` event.

Here's an example of how to do that:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    var tm = setInterval(function() {

            //doSomething();
            b.pinMode('P8_19', b.INPUT);
            value = b.digitalRead('P8_19');

            if (value == lastflowpinstate) 
            {
            lastflowratetimer++;
            //return; // nothing changed!
            }

            if (value == '1') 
            {
               //low to high transition!
               pulses++;
            }

            lastflowpinstate = value;
            flowrate = 1000.0;
            flowrate /= lastflowratetimer;  // in hertz
            lastflowratetimer = 0;

            liters = pulses / (450);
            fulldata += liters;
            //send temperature reading out to connected clients
            socket.emit('water', {'water': fulldata});

    }, 500);

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        clearInterval(tm);
    });

    //function doSomething() {

 });
```

Comment: @LockX - see the comments I added about the disconnect event too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip.  I modified my server code, and I wanted to know if there was any way to test if it actually turns off the timer.

Comment: @LockX - Put a `console.log("running interval timer")` inside the timer callback and see if it keeps outputting or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip (about turning off the timer).  I made some edits in the server code,  but I'm not sure if they're correct.

```
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {

            function to_start()
            {
                tm=window.setInterval('timer()', 500);
            }

            to_start();

            function timer()
            {
               ....
            }

            socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                window.clearInterval(tm);
            });

 });
```

Comment: See my answer for a way to do this.  You have to make sure the `tm` variable has the right scope so it ONLY applies to this particular socket and so each separate socket has it's own `tm` variable.  Also, this should not be posted as an answer to your question.